# Given $a$, $b$ are integers with $a > b$ and the two roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ of the equation $3x^2 + 3(a+b)x + 4ab = 0$ satisfy a relation

Tags: roots, quadratics, integers, discriminant

> Given $a$, $b$ are integers with $a > b$ and the two roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ of the equation $3x^2 + 3(a+b)x + 4ab = 0$ satisfy the relation $$\alpha(\alpha + 1) + \beta(\beta + 1) = (\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)$$, find all the pairs $(a, b)$ of two integers.

Greetings, I was doing the above question related to number theory. I could not complete the question.

Here's what I've done so far:

> Note that $\alpha + \beta = -(a + b)$ and $\alpha \beta = \frac{4ab}{3}$.
>   Now expanding $\alpha(\alpha + 1) + \beta(\beta + 1) = (\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)$ gives us $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - \alpha \beta = 1$. Thus, $(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 3\alpha \beta = 1$.
>   Substituting and doing some calculations, we get $a - b = 1$.

Now I can't proceed further. I don't know if this problem has been posted earlier on MSE (I have checked though).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I think you're only supposed to find the form of the ordered pair $(a,b)=(b+1,b),b\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, we have $b=a-1$ and 
$$3x^2+3(2a-1)x+4a(a-1)=0,$$ which gives
$$9(2a-1)^2-4\cdot3\cdot4a(a-1)\geq0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I am afraid $a+b\ne1$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Thank you! I fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using $b=a-1$, the equation is:

$$3x^2+3(2a-1)x+4a(a-1)=0$$

The discriminant

$$9+12a-12a^2$$

is positive only for the integers $a=0$ and $a=1$